# Breakpoints not binding in language server protocol extension

Tags: typescript, vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

We are building our LSP extension using the [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/lsp-sample) as a basis. Breakpoints are binding successfully for code in the `client` folder but not in the `server` folder. Our launch configs are very similar to the ones in the sample and all our typescript gets compiled into the `out` folder.

```
{
      "type": "extensionHost",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Client: SB Text Editor",
      "runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",
      "args": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/client/testFixture",
        "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceRoot}"
      ],
      "outFiles": [
        "${workspaceRoot}/client/out/**/*.js",
        "${workspaceRoot}/server/out/**/*.js"
      ],
      "sourceMaps": true
    },
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Attach to Server: SB Text Editor LSP",
      "port": 6009,
      "restart": true,
      "outFiles": [
        "${workspaceRoot}/server/out/**/*.js",
        "${workspaceRoot}/server/out/"
      ],
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "trace": true,
      "timeout": 30000
    },
```

We use a compound similar to the one in the sample too.

```
    {
      "name": "SB Text Editor",
      "configurations": [
        "Launch Client: SB Text Editor",
        "Attach to Server: SB Text Editor LSP"
      ],
      "preLaunchTask": "build",
      "outFiles": [
        "${workspaceRoot}/client/out/**/*.js",
        "${workspaceRoot}/server/out/**/*.js"
      ],
      "sourceMaps": true
    },
```

[image]

Checking the Debug Diagnostics and we can see that the code in `server` is not being loaded, only the code in `client`. Are we missing something to get the server code to load for breakpoint binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We got this working by adding this to our client launch config so that the child server processes gets covered:

`"autoAttachChildProcesses": true`